# DRF Handling Password Reset Email

Tags: django-rest-framework, change-password, forgot-password, reset-password

I am new to Django Rest Framework and working on a DRF & React Authentication system. Everything is working fine except password reset. The issue I have is when the user requests a password reset a reset URL with the generated token is fired to the registered email. So the user can click the link with the embedded token and go back to the calling (or any other) URL.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/password_reset/validate_token/?token=wBBAIfQHzTJVz9bKPLkIgB
The problem is how do I generate the view or serializer to handle the URL with the token on the fly. I just need to understand the full flow I am working with "django-rest-passwordreset1.2.1", (https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-passwordreset/) package so I am generating the reset email and token with the model which as per documentation fires a signal to generate the token and send an email. The endpoints that come with the documentation validate and work fine in postman testing.   I am just not sure how to create that functionality in Django. Any help or links to a good tutorial will be appreciated.
Many thanks in advance

models.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.urls import reverse
from django_rest_passwordreset.signals import reset_password_token_created
from django.core.mail import send_mail 

@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def password_reset_token_created(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, 
                                                                   **kwargs):
site = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'

email_plaintext_message = "{}?token={}".format(reverse('password_reset:reset-password-validate'), reset_password_token.key)
reset_url = site + email_plaintext_message

send_mail(
    "Password Reset for {title}".format(title="Some website title"),
    reset_url,
    "noreply@somehost.local",
    [reset_password_token.user.email]
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('api/auth', include('knox.urls')),
  path('api/auth/register', RegisterAPI.as_view()),
  path('api/auth/login', LoginAPI.as_view()),
  path('api/auth/user', UserAPI.as_view()),
  path('api/auth/logout', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="knox_logout"),
  path('api/auth/change-password/', ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name='change-password')
  path('api/auth/password_reset/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
]
```

The include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls')) provides the following url's:
**POST ${API_URL}/** -
*request a reset password token by using the email parameter**
**POST ${API_URL}/confirm/** -
*using a valid token, the users password is set to the provided password*
**POST ${API_URL}/validate_token/** -
*will return a 200 if a given token is valid*
where **${API_URL}/** is the url specified in your urls.py (e.g., api/auth/password_reset/ as in the example above)*

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's abstract from libs, and get proper steps to make it manually.

As far as I've got, you have some token `token=wBBAIfQHzTJVz9bKPLkIgB`  that somehow linked with the User instance, am I right?

So we need to write a view that allows us to make auth and get a request with our User and then we can check the token and make a logout.

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

@api_view["GET"]
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def logout(request):
   if request.query_params.get("token"):
       if Token.objects.filter(token=request.query_params["token"]).exists()
          logout(request)

          # other logic is here

          return Response({"status": "logged out"})
   return Response({"error": "..."})
```

Point your urls.py file to use this API view in the needed path.

So my assumption here is that you are using something like `TokenAuthentication` you can change the decorator's parameter to your actual value. The same thing is for the permission_classes decorator.

Comment: Thanks for your tip buddy but perhaps I phrased the question incorrectly, my issue was not the authentication token but the token generated for resetting the forgotten password.  For authentication token I am using django-knox and for resetting password django-rest-passwordreset library.  Anyway I have solved it, answer below. Thanks for your tip non the less

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the front end, I was able to modify the parameters in the model that generated and stored the token by replacing the URL.  I changed

```
email_plaintext_message = "{}?token={}".format(reverse('password_reset:reset-password-validate'), reset_password_token.key)
```

to the following

```
    email_plaintext_message = "{}?token={}".format('http://127.0.0.1:3000/newpassword' , reset_password_token.key)
```

Now the return URL is http://127.0.0.1:3000/newpassword?token=f109f93a83040895e3a8b1b8afd

pointing to the correct component in the fornt-end.  I then extract the token from the URL and pass it for validation along with the new password in the form hitting the required endpoint.